# Date Validation in BSD MacOSX validates month but not day

Tags: bash, macos, validation, date, sh

I'm using the following code to validate an input  date in `mm/dd/yy` format

```
    date -jf "%m/%d/%y" "$1" > /dev/null 2&>1 
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "The date entered seems to be wrong. Can you please recheck once?"
        exit 2
    else
        echo "$1"
   fi
```

The above code is in shell script `checkDate.sh`.

`checkDate.sh 9/15/16`, works fine.
`checkDate.sh 22/15/16`, throws error message as expected since invalid month 22.
`checkDate.sh 9/31/16`, works fine even when the date 31 Sept is invalid.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `date -jf "%m/%d/%y" "9/31/16"`?

Comment: The output is `Sat Oct  1 18:20:57 IST 2016`. seems that since time is not specified, overlap happens and it crosses to next day?

Comment: Even that isn't guaranteed; `12/32/16` doesn't convert to `1/1/17`.

Comment: I suspect it only tries to rollover if the day is valid for *some* month.

Comment: @chepner and within the same year, I suppose.

Comment: I think the year is irrelevant; every month fails for day 32, but February rolls over to March for both 30 and 31. Just some inconsistent, opportunistic logic where it appears to first verify that the day is between 1 and 31, then if it notes that the month doesn't actually have the given day, it rolls over to the next month.